# Javascript effect works in "Incognito mode" only (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm experiencing a very weird Javascript bug in Chrome.

I've made a website for a client in which the site's background images change as you scroll down. In addition, there's a subtle cross-fade effect between the previous background image and the next one.

Everything works fine in most recent browsers, except for Chrome. Weirder than that: in works in Chrome's incognito mode, but not in the "standard"/initial mode of Chrome. My first reflex was of course to delete all of the browser's data and restart Chrome, but this strangely doesn't fix the problem.

Here is the site's URL: [ link removed by author ]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It works fine for me in chrome with and without incognito.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've cleared my cache again, disabled my add-ons, checked to see if I had the latest version of Chrome... and still nothing. I'll continue testing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already cleared the data, I would guess its because of some extensions that prevent your script from running. In incognito mode, all of them are disabled and your script works.

And further your site works at our end on chrome, so its for sure some addon.

Comment: Thanks, it was AdBlock. I didn't think it was it, because I checked the "Disable on this page" option in the plugin's menu. Still, it looks like it was active, since disabling it altogether corrected the problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a cache issue on your end.  Your page works fine for me.  Try Control+F5.

Your suspicions were correct... by using Incognito Mode, you essentially get a clean session and empty cache.

You can also test this with an extension I wrote that will launch a new Chrome window with empty cache and empty cookies:

http://www.musatcha.com/software/NewChromeSession/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I knew about the CTRL+F5 shortcut, but it hasn't corrected the problem. Disabling my add-ons (the only one being AdBlock) didn't help either. I'll try your extension or reinstall Chrome altogether...

Answer (score 0):

If the cache issue doesn't work, make sure you have no plugins interfering

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. In my configuration the Chrome Touch Extension is producing the error. After disabling it, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps - reinstall Chrome.

In my case I tried clearing all caches, uninstalling all extensions, disabling antivirus but only reinstall solved this issue.

Interestingly issue was happening only to specific user account on Chrome, everything worked fine in incognito, other account and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the Chrome EndNote extension, and that fixed the problem for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35492159)