# Chrome shows new page only in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-chrome

I deployed new feature to my website.
The feature is not visible in Google Chrome.

Ctrl+r  nor Shift+F5 helps

When I switch to incognito mode it is visble.
It is visible in Internet Explorer.

Chrome steadidy shows the new features (in normal mode) as soon as once Development Mode is switched on with "Disable cache" active.

How can I tell Chrome to refresh  my page in its cache? Ideally from the server (html header), so that all my users get the new feature.

The Rails assets pipeline creates versions of my minified JS. Currently I'm loading "/assets/application-994bdd4fb9d2b5ecca17a94c89410e71.js".

All Chrome PlugIns are disabled. Colleagues PC's show same behavior.

**Feature Discription**:
Page is Rails Backend with AngularJS 1.x frontend. Data loaded by Angular are always fresh. But any new Javascript/HTML feature is simply not shown. No errors, simply the older page. Even the version number of the page differs from normal to incognito mode.

Chrome Version: 48.0.2564.103 m

Comment: Is it using HTML5 offline mode (cache manifest)?

Comment: I don't think I use HTML5 offline mode. How could I check this?

Comment: All AddOns/PlugIns are disabled. This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018256/javascript-effect-works-in-incognito-mode-only-chrome